# Send link to update DB with Data

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios4

In our iPhone app , we offer email templates populated with DB. also user can create their own templates.

Say for example , i have my own templates created over 500 entries to use

here i need to know  the possibility on the below things since my client asks me.

If i want to to send my templates stored into my DB to myfriend who uses the same application.( So my friend does not have to create the templets on his own , he can use mine)
Can that user be able to load those template details ( DB information ) into his app? (like posting the db contents to server and the same content can be loaded into his app using link)

I think it cant be done but i would like to know opinions and views to convey this to my superior.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This could help: [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781290/644629)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well.. It's possible to do what you are trying to do.
You would need to

1. Serialize the data that's stored in the DB
2. Figure out a way to send this data to the server/as an attachment in an email over to your friend.

So from that point of view,

1. Doing the first is pretty simple. If its all just string content, you can serialize it into an XML/JSON. There are a lot of ways out there that converts objects into strings or bytes to send them over the network anywhere you please.
2. The second needs support from the server. You would need a server that can identify the applications from one another. ie. yours from that of your friend's. It should then be made to handle the serialized content you are planning to send over and then figure out a way to send it to the friend. maybe a push notification? You could possibly look at Urban Airship or some such offering for doing this incase you dont have an existing server.

Or, you can cut yourself all the work and see if your workflow can fit into this
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app